# Setting up a secure Web Service

Tags: web-services, iis, asmx, wcf-security, security

I need to set up a web service. Server is in DMZ, so I thought about putting web service in IIS (asmx) cos only port 80 is available to comunicate. But information it provides should be secured. What choices do I have when it comes to what .NET / IIS can offer ?

Or maybe I should dispense with asxm web service and switch to something else. But once again, I only have port 80 available.

Thanks,
Pawel

Comment: I believe you can do this using WCF, but there's no way to do it with the old ASMX services.

Comment: Thx. So even though I have IIS running on port 80, I'm capable of using WCF with binding configured to HTTP port 80?

Comment: [You can run WCF inside IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx). Remember that web services [are exposed as endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751841.aspx) which simply means exposing an address where to find the web service.

Answer (score 1):

**You should checkout WCF**

When it comes to securing web services you have to main action paths:

- go for communication over HTTPS and leave the web service messages in plain text (no problem since the data is over HTTPS and you can't see inside): transport level security;
- go for communication over HTTP but secure the messages of the web service (WS-Security fits this role): message level security.

WS-* specifications are not an easy thing to digest (especialy WS-Security which relies on other specs like WS-Policy, WS-Addressing, XML Signature, XML Encryption etc). But since you say you only have port 80 available for communication I think you don't have a choice (don't even think of implementing your own security mechanism :D).

So, if you have to use WS-Security then go for WCF. You have [a bunch of communication mechanism you can choose from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx) and WCF takes a lot of the heavy lifting for you, abstracting away the "bare metal" of SOAP and WS-*.

Answer (score 0):

Within IIS, if you wish to only allow a specific IP address to access the web service, do the following:

1. Within IIS, right click on the file with asmx extension.  Click “Switch to features view”
2. Click the “IP Address and Domain Restrictions” icon.
   [image]
3. Click “Edit Feature Settings”, Select Deny All, Add Allow Entry.
   [image]
4. Type in the IP you want the service to access.